# How to get the data in dbf file while creating shapefile using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I am using ArcObject DLL to create shapefile. I am successfully able to create the shapefile but I am having some issues with populating the shapefile data into .dbf file. At present the .dbf file just contains the column names but the dataset is empty.

[image: Excel screenshot]

I adding the data in db file as follows

```c#
 public IFields CreateFieldsCollectionForFeatureClass(ISpatialReference spatialReference, string ViewType, DataSet ds)
    {
        //IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)annotationLayer;
        IFeatureClassDescription fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();
        IObjectClassDescription ocDesc = (IObjectClassDescription)fcDesc;

        // Create the fields using the required fields method.
        IFields fields = ocDesc.RequiredFields;

        // Locate the shape field with the name from the feature class description.
        int shapeFieldIndex = fields.FindField(fcDesc.ShapeFieldName);
        IField shapeField = fields.get_Field(shapeFieldIndex);

        // Modify the GeometryDef object before using the fields collection to create a new feature class.
        IGeometryDef geometryDef = shapeField.GeometryDef;
        IGeometryDefEdit geometryDefEdit = (IGeometryDefEdit)geometryDef;

        // Alter the feature class geometry type to lines (default is polygons).
        if (ViewType == ViewsType.Powerplant.ToString())
        {
            geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryMultipoint;
        }
        else if (ViewType == ViewsType.Pipeline.ToString())
        {
            geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline;
        }
        else if (ViewType == ViewsType.Facility.ToString())
        {
            geometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryMultipoint;
        }
        geometryDefEdit.HasM_2 = true;
        geometryDefEdit.GridCount_2 = 1;

        // Set the first grid size to zero and allow ArcGIS to determine a valid grid size.
        geometryDefEdit.set_GridSize(0, 0);
        geometryDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = spatialReference;

        // Because the fields collection already exists, the AddField method on the IFieldsEdit interface
        // will be used to add a field that is not required to the fields collection.
        IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)fields;
        foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            IField filed = new FieldClass();
            IFieldEdit editFiled = (IFieldEdit)filed;
            editFiled.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
            editFiled.Name_2 = col.ColumnName;
            editFiled.DefaultValue_2 = "test";//ds.Tables[0].Rows;
            //foreach (DataRow d in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            //{
            //    editFiled.DefaultValue_2 = d["ID"];
            //}

            //editFiled.DefaultValue_2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            editFiled.Length_2 = 50;
            fieldsEdit.AddField(editFiled);
        }
        //fields = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFields)fieldsEdit;

        return fields;
    }
```

How can I get the data of that field in .dbf file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get features into a shapefile, One is with [IFeatureClass.CreateFeature()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateFeature_Method/0025000002sz000000/) followed by [IFeature.store()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000) and the other is with [IFeatureCursor.InsertFeature()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002w0000000) on a IFeatureBuffer created from the IFeatureClass using [CreateFeatureBuffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateFeatureBuffer_Method/0025000002t0000000/)

The fastest way is with IFeatureCursor:

```
IFeatureCursor pCur = pFeatureClass.InsertCursor; //pFeatureClass is an IFeatureClass
IFeatBuff pFtBuff = pFeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
// A feature buffer has the same properties as a feature
pFtBuff.shape = pYourGeometry; // a geometry you've created
pFtBuff.set_Value(indx) = pSomeValue; // indx is the index of the field
// do that a few times..
// fields are from 0 to fieldcount - 1
pCur.InsertFeature(pFtBuff);
```

If you have a lot of features to store then it's a good idea to call the Flush() on the cursor from time to time.

After you've finished with the cursor and buffer get rid of them using [ReleaseComObject](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v%3Dvs.71%29.aspx&ei=OKauU8yiDYHgkAWjsIDgBQ&usg=AFQjCNFlovzMWuSQ9dMtVPE7FblJWeZu5A&bvm=bv.69837884,d.dGI) to do the final flush and release the locks on the file.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your reply. I didn't understand that so can you please explain me in detail if possible.?

Comment: Values in the dbf file belongs to features - a row with a geometry and ID. You can't have values without meeting that condition. The code is how to create, set the attributes and then store a feature (row) in the shapefile.

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for your reply I tried the solution you mentioned, I'm getting a error can you please look into it , the error is here http://webashlar.com/Demos/images/Untitled.png

Comment: It's hard to tell from that error message, it's fairly generic. What is field 1? The value is a variant so if field 1 is not a string then remove the quotes and set it as a number, if it's a geometry don't set it *that* way, geometries are set by *pFtBuff.Shape = Geometry*. You will also get that error if the field is read-only.

Comment: I have tried this and i am successfully added data in the dbf but now the problem is that in the dbf the first row is blank so thats why when i selects one geometry its select all geometry so for that any solution my code is.

IGeometry pol = GetMultipointGeometry(ds,LogfilePath,ViewName) /*  */
pFeature.Shape = pol; this is for Geometry feature.
then after i am inserting data in dbf file code:

IFeatureBuffer pFtBuff = FC.CreateFeatureBuffer();
int t = pFtBuff.Fields.FindField(dc.ColumnName);
pFtBuff.set_Value(t, value);j++;}}pFtBuff.Shape = g;
pCur.InsertFeature(pFtBuff);pCur.Flush();}

Comment: Shouldn't pFtBuff.Shape be pol? Check to see if you are inserting an empty row first, can you edit your question with your revised code please.